# Converting depth map, stored in a Mat to a point cloud using pcl

Tags: c++, opencv, projection, point-cloud-library

I have a PNG image that I have stored in a Mat (16UC1).

Is there a fast way to project a depth map into a point cloud using point cloud library? And after this: is there a fast way to project a point taken on that image into point cloud?

I have to use as reference system that one that is located at the center of the IR sensor on Kinect.

I would appreciate a kind of guide, if it's possible, thank you a lot!

Comment: It's relative. Fast compared to what?

Comment: First, thanks to Victor for re-editing my question.
Fast as "simple to use", for example build a point cloud from an image just calling a function

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem: I used [this](http://www.pcl-users.org/Getting-strange-results-when-moving-from-depth-map-to-point-cloud-td4025104.html#a4025138) system and [these](https://vision.in.tum.de/data/datasets/rgbd-dataset/file_formats) camera parameters, except the focal length I knew.

Every cameras have its parameters, but I had to work on a particular sequence and camera's parameters were not supplied (except focal length). So it's an approximation.